# How to make ocean drainage map using Python

Tags: python, geopandas, basin, ocean

I'd like to make ocean drainage map like this:
[image]

In particular I'm interested in Russia.
A relatively explicit data source is hydrosheds.org, however from there i can get data to display only endorheic basins. As a last resort I thought to try to highlight ocean basins by the touch of the basins to the oceans.